# how to change size of grid layout cells using flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, flot

I want to change size of grid layout cells. But when i find [API](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) of `jquery flot`, i didn't find any method which use to change size of grid layout cells.

This is image which i want to change size of grid layout cells (horizontal + vertical) to bigger. How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let options_hour = {
series: {
    lines: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 1.2
    }
},
grid: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    borderWidth: {
        top: 1,
        right: 1,
        bottom: 1,
        left: 1
    },
    highlightColor: "#FF0000"
},
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timezone: "browser",
    show: true,
    ticks: 9,
    tickColor: "#000000",
    min: initialize_hour - 3600000 * 6,
    max: initialize_hour - 600000,
    ticks: [
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 6,
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 5,
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 4,
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 3,
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 2,
        initialize_hour - 3600000 * 1,
        initialize_hour - 600000
    ],
    font: {
        size: 9,
        color: "#980000"
    },
    timeformat: "%H:%M"
},
yaxis: {
    font: {
        size: 9,
        color: "#980000"
    },
    min: 0,
    ticks: [
        [0, '0'],
        [2.25, 'NNW'],
        [4.5, 'NW'],
        [6.75, 'WNW'],
        [9, 'W'],
        [11.25, 'WSW'],
        [13.5, 'SW'],
        [15.75, 'SSW'],
        [18, 'S'],
        [20.25, 'SSE'],
        [22.5, 'SE'],
        [24.75, 'ESE'],
        [27, 'E'],
        [29.25, 'ENE'],
        [31.5, 'NE'],
        [33.75, 'NNE'],
        [36, 'N']
    ],
    tickColor: "#000000"
}
```

};

Comment: Did you try increasing the Div height/width?

Comment: I use inspect element and it's only a canvans.
`<canvas class="flot-overlay" width="537" height="230" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 537px; height: 230px;"></canvas>`

So, height/width, can you explain clearly ?